# Is it possible to get new permission for installed app by update?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-internet

I want to know is it possible to get new permission(say INTERNET permission) which was not given while installing app through android market but to get while updating. For example im giving free version of my app without ads, later after some time if i want to update the existing user and new user with ads(by updating permission in manifest) is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the new permission will be shown to users when they update. Adding ads to an existing free app might not be the best idea thought -- it is sure to give you a bunch of 1-star ratings.